# Which JSON structure that works with minimal fuss across Rust, Swift, Kotlin

Tags: json, swift, kotlin, rust, serde

I need to pass data from Rust to Android(Kotlin) & iOS(Swift). I can control all the pipelines.

My problem is that different representations change how much effort is in coding the mobile side, what is the "easy/default" in one makes the other side the need to fill *manual decode/encode boilerplate* (this is what I wish to avoid!).

This is not scalable because I will have dozens of potential structs across *the 3 languages*.

My ideal is to write not more complex than:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub enum Request {
    Menu { company: String },
}
```

```swift
enum Request: Codable {
    case Menu(company:String)
}
```

```kotlin
@Serializable
sealed class Request {
    @Serializable
    class Menu(val company: String) : Request()
}
```

This is mostly about enums. Exist many ways to represent enums in json:

https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Message {
    Request { id: String, method: String, params: Params },
    Response { id: String, result: Value },
}
```

#### Externally tagged

```json
{"Request": {"id": "...", "method": "...", "params": {...}}}
```

#### Internally tagged

```json
{"type": "Request", "id": "...", "method": "...", "params": {...}}
```

#### Adjacently tagged

```json
{"t": "Para", "c": [{...}, {...}]}
{"t": "Str", "c": "the string"}
```

#### Untagged

```json
{"id": "...", "method": "...", "params": {...}}
```

---

Kotlin serialization looks like the default is "Internally tagged" but Swift is "Externally tagged".

So, how unify all?

Comment: Not what you're asking directly, but tools like capn'n proto and protobufs allow you to just define 1 file describing messages, and auto-generate code to work with those messages on different systems

Comment: "Easiest" is going to be subjective — as you note, the defaults are going to be different across the different languages, so somewhere you'll almost certainly need to fill in boilerplate. Have you tried looking into which language makes it easiest to write that boilerplate (or tooling to automate it in some way)? What criterion here would you consider to be "success"?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by making the switch on Rust instead with conditional compilation, to match the defaults in the mobile side:

```rust
#[cfg(not(target_os = "android"))]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub enum Response {
    Menu { modules: Vec<Menu> },
    Fail(JsonError),
}

#[cfg(target_os = "android")]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
pub enum Response {
    Menu { modules: Vec<Menu> },
    Fail(JsonError),
}
```